# Is there a way to get the mouse's X and Y coordinates in MIT Scheme?

Tags: x11, mit-scheme

I've been experimenting with X Graphics in MIT Scheme, and I was wondering whether there is a way to get the cursor position on the screen/in relation to the X window from within the language, to change the graphics based on the mouse location.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way myself, but it's pretty nasty since I had to use additional packages:

```
(define (get-position) 
        (define a (open-output-string))
        (run-shell-command "xdotool getmouselocation" 'output a)
        (define output (get-output-string a))
        (close-port a)
        ((lambda (x) (list (string->number (cadar x)) (string->number (cadadr x))))
         (map (string-splitter 'delimiter #\:) ((string-splitter) ((string-trimmer) output)))))

(define resolution (let ((a (open-output-string)))
                        (run-shell-command "xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | awk '{print $2;}'" 'output a)
                        (define output (get-output-string a))
                        (close-port a)
                        (map string->number ((string-splitter 'delimiter #\x)
                                            ((string-trimmer) output)))))
```

Then, to get the relative position of the cursor on the screen, you just do

```
(map (lambda (x y) (inexact (/ x y))) (get-position) resolution)
```

(You do have install xdpyinfo and xdotool beforehand though, so keep that in mind)